# Games for russian vocabulary

Tags: грамматика

Looking for online games to improve my vocabulary and grammar, do you know of any?

Comment: Try playing scrabble - in Russian it is called "эрудит". But be careful to find an online game that explains the meaning of words, otherwise it will be useless.

Comment: Ergh. I strongly recommend to not play games, but read texts and dwell forums/blogs. There is a huge collection of free texts in russian known at http://lib.ru, and even larger collection of beginning authors/graphomaniacs/ficwriters  at http://samlib.ru Both have primitive commenting systems, so you will be able to expand active vocabulary and grammar as well.

Comment: @permeakra, last people you want to learn language from are beginner graphomaniacs, and Internet commentators.

Comment: Vote to close, as it is right now framed more of a listing question. Can be fixed if turned into community wiki, added to our list of resources on meta, or made more specific.

Comment: Community wiki sounds good, finding resources like games to play is quite hard.

Comment: Simply crosswords.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this game is for beginner, but proposing anyway - [Балда](http://www.naturalist.ru/balda/balda.html). This game will improve your vocabulary.
The user can set the opponent's smartness level.

**UPDATE:** The words used during the game are shown in the list as hyperlinks to explanatory/spelling/etymological dictionaries ([example](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%97/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/)). Though the dictionaries are Russian, but they say that the best way to understand the meaning of the word is to use native explanatory dictionaries.

Here are the rules (from the site):

> Правила игры в Балду.
>
> Играют двое (в данном случае Вы и моя программа). В середине поля, состоящего из 25 клеток, выбирается слово из пяти букв.
>
> Ваш ход первый - Вы должны придумать новое слово, состоящее из уже находящихся на поле букв и обязательно одной новой буквы, которую вы добавляете.
>
> Чем длиннее слово вы придумаете, тем больше очков Вы получаете.
>   Одна буква - одно очко.
>
> Потом, с добавлением новой буквы, ходит соперник и так далее по очереди.
>   Слова в одной игре повторяться не могут.
>
> Игра завершается при заполнении последней клетки поля. Выигрывает тот, у кого больше очков.

Answer (score 0):

There are some fun games on the [RussianForFree.com website](http://www.russianforfree.com/quizzes-to-learn-russian.php).

In addition to easy to follow courses, they have other interesting resources as well, such as:

- [Music Videos](http://www.russianforfree.com/music-videos-in-russian.php) (with translated lyrics)
- [Cartoons](http://www.russianforfree.com/cartoons-in-russian.php) (with translations)
- [Comics](http://www.russianforfree.com/comics-in-russian.php) (also with translations)

Answer (score 0):

Try a game of [mafia](http://mafiaweb.ru/). Conviencing people that you killed nobody will sure improve your vocabulary. Might be pretty hard, but after a few games of remaining silent you will remember all the mostly used expressions and will be able to learn more complex things.

Comment: The OP is asking about _online_ games.  I've never seen online game of mafia: most of the play is dependent on your actual feelings (sight, hearing, etc.)

Comment: True that it's different when played online, but there are a lot of online mafia web-sites. There everything relies on how you explain yourself in chat, so that might be good for OP.